# Google Map Markers Scope Problem

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am able to get the lat/lng coordinates, but somehow the system sets the center point of the map to (0,0).  Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction for how to get the right lat/lng to become my center points?

The url where I am testing this is here:
http://www.comehike.com/hikes/hike_carpool.php?hike_id=125

Thank you,
Alex

Comment: @genadinik do u have the markers you wish to display saved on the map, and just basically want the center of thoese markers? so, you want the center point between the red marker, the car, and the smiley face?

Comment: There is a lat/lng for the center, and I want the marker to appear at the center.  But can't get it to do that. :(  ...and yes, in this case the center point would be between the car and smiley face.

Comment: @Genadinik so, you really didn't want the red marker to be placed on the map as the center point am i correct?

Comment: Actually, I do want to place the red marker :)  Just for me, it doesn't get placed at the right coordinates.  For me, for some reason, it is at (0,0) instead of the right coordinates.

Comment: do a console.log(); on that red marker coordinate

Comment: Why?  I already debugged this and the debugging was strange.  Thats why I posted here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just looked at your code:

```
var lat = 0;
var lng = 0;

request.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    ...
    lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
    lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
    ...
} // Closing onReadyStateChange

request.send(null);

var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat , lng ); // Have to make the center as the hike coordinates.
var myOptions =
{
    zoom: 9,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
```

map is set to (0,0) because you defined `lat, lng` so, looks like you rely on lat, lng changing in ajax callback function, but it is asynchronous, so when browser gets to

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat , lng );
```

`lat` and `lng` in 99.99% cases will be 0, and only after some time (depending on network etc.) they will be changed, but it will be after map is built... Otherwise you have to create your map in callback function:

```
function createMap( lat, lng ) 
{
   var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat , lng ); // Have to make the center as the hike coordinates.
    var myOptions =
    {
        zoom: 9,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    return new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);    
}

function initialize( hike_id ) {
  var lat = 0;
  var lng = 0;
  var map;

  request.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
      ...
      lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
      lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
      ...
      map = createMap( lat, lng );

   } // Closing onReadyStateChange

   request.send(null);
}
```

shortly, you have to be sure lat and lng are defined as you need before map creation... This way it should work. Alternatively you can create map with center in (0,0) or somewhere else, but predefined, and then in ajax callback use `map.setCenter( center_latlng );`

also you do not create markers... your callback has

```
// create the marker
center_latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( lat , lng ); 
global_markers[i] = marker;
```

you define center_latlng value, but do not use it.. instead you put `marker` defined outside of callback to your markers array. Should be something like:

```
// create the marker
center_latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( lat , lng ); 
var hikeMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: center_latlng,
   map: map,
   title:"Hike Start"
}); 
global_markers[i] = hikeMarker ;
```

**EDIT:** Took a look at your last implementation:

```
function createMap( center_lat , center_lng ) {
   ...
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions); 
   ...
}
```

that function creates `map` in global scope, that's not good until you really need it to be global. I updated my code above, so I would return map in that function (have a look). Otherwise, if you really need map to be global (meaning that something else could use it), then I would prefer another way (was shortly told above too): create map with center anywhere, then set its center in ajax callback. This way you will be sure that map is created as soon as possible, and you won't get in trouble with "null" value (again if it is used outside initialize method, of even out of ajax callback:

```
function createMap( lat, lng ) 
{
   var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat , lng ); // Have to make the center as the hike coordinates.
    var myOptions =
    {
        zoom: 9,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    return new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);    
}

function initialize( hike_id ) {
  var lat = 0;
  var lng = 0;
  var map = createMap( lat, lng ); // create with center in (0,0); probably would be better to use San Francisco

  request.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
      ...
      lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
      lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
      ...
      map.setCenter( lat, lng ); // it will change position of map to real one

   } // Closing onReadyStateChange

   request.send(null);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I just tried your solution, but it still has (0,0) - could you take a look?  Maybe I didn't do something exactly right?

Comment: @Genadinik: sure, give me few minutes

Comment: @Genadinik: just look like you have find the problem, cause I see map positioned with center in San Francisco

Comment: @Genadinik: and yes, you are right, better to make `createMap` function taking arguments, then rely on global parameters

Comment: @maxym i still standby my answer =P its just better way to dynamically center markers

Answer (score 1):

Add `map.panTo(center_latlng);` after you define center_latlng

Comment: What does that do?  And where exactly should I place that?  Thanks.

Comment: @Genadiniki: from [Google Map API Reference](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map): panTo(latLng:LatLng) - Changes the center of the map to the given LatLng. If the change is less than both the width and height of the map, the transition will be smoothly animated.

Comment: You can place it right after you define values for `center_latlng` variable. It will work as long as you have already instantiated `map`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason i asked if the red marker was placed on the map intentionally is because there's a function in Google Map V3 API that allows dynamic center of map based on the Markers you wish to display.

You can use `var myBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();` and basically extend all the points you have by doing `myBounds.extend(myMarker);` individually. Once you have all the points in the `LatLngBounds()` you can use your `map.fitBounds(myBounds);` and the map would be centered based on the markers that are within bounds.

[Google Map API LatLngBounds](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#LatLngBounds)